# Unable to call method in view using instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In Mvc project I'm Unable to call method in view using instance.
I have used AutoFac for dependency injection.

In HomeController.cs

```
public readonly IMyClass _myClass;

public HomeController(IMyClass myClass)
{
    _myClass = myClass;
}
```

In MyClass I have one Translate method which takes string as a parameter and gives converted string as a output based on language code.

I did it in controller which is working fine .

```
  var myModel = new MyModel
            {
                Message = _myClass.Translate("Welcome")

            };
return View("Index", myModel);
```

But I do not want it through `Model` I would like to call `Translate` in `View`

I tried to call this `Translate method` from `Index.cshtml` view like following:

```
_myClass.Translate("Welcome")
```

I think I missed something but what?

Comment: What do you mean by can't call a method? How do you access your controller's fields - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417168/asp-net-mvc-access-controller-instance-from-view?

Comment: Why would you want to call a method on your Controller from a view!? You even attempting to do this is bad practise. What you need to do is whatever that Method is doing, return it to the View with the Model.

Comment: Call it in the action method and pass the result to the view using a model or view bag.

Comment: MVC does not work like asp with code behind pages, what you are trying to do is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many acceptable options .. what you're doing isn't one of them.

I personally wouldn't pass it all down with the model .. your models will become quite bloated.

One option would be an extension method for `HtmlHelper`:

```
public static class TranslationExtensions {
    public static IMvcHtmlString Translate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input) { // or just "string" if you're not accepting markup
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(<logic to translate input here>);
    }
}
```

Then in your view .. at the top:

```
@using Your.Namespace.Where.The.Extensions.Class.Is
```

... and then:

```
@Html.Translate("Welcome")
```

This pattern can be used to extend existing helpers as well and is something you should investigate. For example, to create a label with translated text .. you could potentially create something that allows this:

```
@Html.TranslatedLabelFor(x => x.ModelProperty)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing isn't working because you cannot arbitrarily call methods on your controller - or its fields - from within your view. And you shouldn't try to. Give the view everything it needs in the first place.

I have achieved this by marking the view model properties that need to be translated with a custom `TranslatableAttribute`:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Translatable]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the controller (or in a base controller), defining a `TranslatedView` method that uses reflection to identify and translate the appropriate property values:

```
public ActionResult TranslatedView(string viewName, object model)
{
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        /* Using the Castle.Core HasAttribute method - go with whatever
         * you like. */
        if (property.HasAttribute<TranslatableAttribute>())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(model) as string;
            if (value != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(model, _myClass.Translate(value));
            }
        }
    }

    return View(viewName, model);
}
```

Obviously, this can be made as sophisticated as it needs to be - overload it, wrap it up into a custom `ActionResult`... whatever you need.

This approach has the advantage that your translation implementation is nicely decoupled from your web app, which can be tricky to achieve with custom helpers. Helpers tend to be more suited to situations where you don't need to rely on services and can work happily within the context provided by the helper itself.

Comment: I did the same like this in controller but i do not want it with model i want to call it on View
 ` var myModel = new MyModel
            {
                Message = _myClass.Translate("Welcome")
              
            };`

Comment: No you don't. There is no good reason to do this in the view. Why do you want to break conventions like this?